# Using getline to read either just a newline or text

Tags: c++, newline, getline, cin

So what I need to do is get input from a user, a filename specifically, with the alternative of the user just pressing enter to default to a certain filename. Here is what I have:

```
cout << "Where should I save the exam (default exam.txt): ";
getline(cin, examfilename);
if (examfilename == "") {
    examfilename = "exam.txt";
}
cout << "Where should I save the key (default key.txt): ";
getline(cin, keyfilename);
if (keyfilename == "") {
    keyfilename = "key.txt";
}
```

And when run, the output is `Where should I save the exam (default exam.txt): Where should I save the key (default key.txt):` all on one line with a blinking cursor at the end.

How could I read in the file names, but also use the default if the user presses enter?

Comment: Just print out a newline if the `examfilename` is empty?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually introduce a newline in the console by like this:

```
if (examfilename == "") {
    examfilename = "exam.txt";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: That causes it to be `Where should I save the exam (default exam.txt): ` Then a newline with `Where should I save the key (default key.txt): ` and the cursor at the end of the second line.

Comment: @user1111098 Then there needs to be a newline inserted at the end of the other if statement.